# input value is "undefined" in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, input, undefined

just recognized strange behaviour in IE9 and i have no idea

ich have this function :

```
function searchProfile(fieldName, term, page, count) {
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',
        data:'fieldName='+fieldName+'&term='+term+'&id=${id}&page='+page+'&count='+count,
        url:'${createLink(action: 'searchProfilByName')}',
        global: false,
        success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#'+fieldName+'_results_div').html(data);},
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});
};
```

and it´s called for example :

```
<div class="button" onclick="searchProfile('netzwerk', netzwerk_searchterm.value, 0, -1)">
```

chrome FF opera safari excellently "`read`"

```
netzwerk_searchterm.value
```

but in IE9 or older theres an error

```
"SCRIPT: 'netzwerk_searchterm' is undefined"
```

`.val()` didn´t work all browsers
anybody got a ninja idea where the error might be ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `netzwerk_searchterm` declared, what is it referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing `netzwerk_searchterm` is the id of the field, write this:

```
<div class="button" onclick="searchProfile('netzwerk', jQuery('#netzwerk_searchterm').val(), 0, -1)">
```

As you have got jQuery already.

Comment: yeah thats it, already tryied that but got a bit confused with sytnax because "netzwerk" is a variable, and i didnt properly inserted it, but working fine now =) thanks to you all, very fast answers

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `document.getElementById()`

like

```
searchProfile('netzwerk', document.getElementById('netzwerk_searchterm').value, 0, -1)
```

Comment: that works nice, is there any special reason to prefer rather this way than jQuery selector ?

Comment: Your existing code was already in javascript , so I worte it so... and  this will also work wehter you are using jquery lib or not

Answer (score 1):

Did you define `netzwerk_searchterm` as a variable?

I'd say you are trying to access the value of some input field so you should do:

```
$('input#netzwerk_searchterm').val()
```

E.g.:

```
<div class="button" onclick="searchProfile('netzwerk', $('input#netzwerk_searchterm').val(), 0, -1)">
```

Comment: If you're selecting by id, don't add any other fluff, as id is already unique, so `$('#netzwerk_searchterm')` does not need the `input` added to it.

Comment: @RenéWolferink You'd be surprised how many websites are on the web using id's that are not unique though. And the "other fluff" does not do any harm, while it does prevent people from posting new questions here when they see "abnormal behavior" due to that.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is, you can move the "netzwerk_searchterm.value" part from method arguments and put it directly in the function, this is what I mean:

```
 function searchProfile(fieldName, page, count) {
    var term = $('input#netzwerk_searchterm').val(); //NOTE this
    if(!term)
       term = '*'; //you can even customhouse the search term
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',
        data:'fieldName='+fieldName+'&term='+term+'&id=${id}&page='+page+'&count='+count,
        url:'${createLink(action: 'searchProfilByName')}',
        global: false,
        success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#'+fieldName+'_results_div').html(data);},
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});
};
```

This is more readable and works in every browser.